# Is there a way to understand trignometry easily and clearly

Tags: reference-request, trigonometry

What should i do to understand trigonometry properly(without any rote).
well!i missed my trigonometry classes at school and finding it hard to learn it on my own....Please help

Comment: ...Study...? Do lots of exercises...?

Comment: Youtube has lots of tutorials available. Just search "trigonometry" or search for specific subtopics on youtube. Also Khanacademy (available on youtube) probably has some good video lectures.

Comment: [WebTrig](http://www.math.uakron.edu/~tprice/Trig/toc.html) is a free online textbook, and after a first pass through Trigonometry, I recommend [Everything you always wanted to know about trig but were afraid to ask](http://math.jhu.edu/~jbaber/trig_review3.pdf) for a refresher of some of the most important facts.

Comment: 1. Read a good textbook (see 3, if you haven't yet decided on one).
2. Solve most textbook' exercises.
3. Keep asking questions on the StackExchange Mathematics.    
 
Good luck and health in 2014!

Comment: Think about what each notation means, and prove the various relations yourself, using geometry on the unit circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get started, you might try visiting [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/trigonometry). If you're lacking any prerequisite knowledge, you can go back a bit and refresh, as well.

A very good book on trigonometry is [Gelfand's](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0817639144). It is written with the student in mind and doesn't read like your usual text.